# Mock firebase functions in cypress

Tags: firebase-authentication, mocking, cypress, integration-testing, sinon

I am using `signInWithEmailAndPassword` from `firebase/auth` to log in my users in my next.js app and I want to write a cypress test for my login page.

I don't want to fire a login request to Firebase in this test. I instead want to mock the output of `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to return the data I need!

I tried this in before each test:

```
    import * as firebaseAuth from 'firebase/auth' 

    cy.stub(firebaseAuth, 'signInWithEmailAndPassword').callsFake(() => {
            return Promise.resolve({ user: { getIdToken: () => token } })
   })
```

but it does not work since it keeps calling the original function.
also tried using `sinon` stubs instead of cypress stubs and I got an error `Descriptor for property signInWithEmailAndPassword is non-configurable and non-writable es6 modules`

also tried wrapping the whole signing in a function a mocking it with `sinon`, and I still get the same error regarding the non-writable es6 modules

could anyone help with this? or either suggest another approach to test my login in Cypress